# Formatear segundos con decimales a minutos, segundos y milisegundos

Tags: php, php7

estoy trabajando con PHP y necesito formatear Segundos con decimales y obtener 00:00:000 (Minutos:Segundos:Milisegundos)

Logre algo pero no estoy seguro si es la manera correcta de hacerlo:

```
$valor = 80.344;
$formato = floor($valor / 60).':'.floor($valor % 60).':'.(explode('.', number_format($valor, 3))[1]);
```

Comment: Hola gustav cuál es el resultado esperado para  el valor de `80.344`

Comment: No entiendo qué quieres hacer. ¿Qué es lo que se guarda en la variable `$valor`? Aparentemente son segundos, pero me gustaría que lo ratificaras ¿El problema es convertir una variable que tiene segundos en minutos:segundos:milisegundos?

Comment: Bienvenido Gustavo. Al preguntar, mientras más precisión mejor... ¿A qué equivale `80.344`? ¿A `80.344` minutos, segundos, milisegundos, nanosegundos, días, meses, semanas, años, trimestres, semestres, años bisiestos, años luz...? ¿Son ochenta mil trescientos cuarenta y cuatro o son ochenta punto trescientos cuarenta y cuatro? Aclarado eso, ¿qué es lo que quieres hacer con ese valor, en qué formato quieres la salida?

Comment: Años luz es una medida de distancia, no tiempo. Just Sayin'

Comment: Son segundos, lo resolví a mi manera, pero necesita un código mucho más limpio como el que me sugirieron, muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si entendí bien tu pregunta, lo que estarías buscando es convertir `$valor` que contiene segundos, a desplegar minutos:segundos:milésimas ¿es correcto?

Si es así, entonces:

```
$valor = 80.344;

// Sacamos los minutos y los restamos de valor
$minutos = floor($valor / 60);
$valor -= $minutos*60;

// Sacamos ahora los segundos y los quitamos de valor
$segundos = floor($valor);
$valor -= $segundos

// Imprimimos formateado:
print(sprintf('%02d', $minutos) . ":" . sprintf('%02d', $segundos) . ':' . sprintf('%3.0f', $valor*1000));
```

80.344 => 01:20:344

Comment: Excelente! Mucho más claro que cómo lo realice. Muchas gracias